# Azure Sentinel: How to install 'Solution' either using a CLI or Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-cli, azure-sentinel

I have created an Azure Sentinel using the following terraform code

```
### Sentinel workspace ###
resource "azurerm_sentinel_data_connector_azure_security_center" "main" {
  name                       = "data-connector-azure-security-center"
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.ws.id
  subscription_id            = data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id
}
```

and connected with various data sources like mentioned below

```
### Data Connector for Active Directory ###
resource "azurerm_sentinel_data_connector_azure_active_directory" "aad" {
  name                       = "Microsoft Entra ID"
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_sentinel_log_analytics_workspace_onboarding.sential.workspace_id
}
```

I need to create an Active Rule based on the existing Rule Templates, like mentioned below

```
### Create a Rule based on the existing Rules Template, you need to install Azure Activity Solution before this ###
data "azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_template" "analytics_rule_template" {
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.ws.id
  display_name               = "Rare subscription-level operations in Azure"
}

resource "azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_scheduled" "rare_operations" {
  name                       = data.azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_template.analytics_rule_template.name
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.ws.id
  alert_rule_template_guid   = data.azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_template.analytics_rule_template.name
  display_name               = data.azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_template.analytics_rule_template.display_name
  severity                   = data.azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_template.analytics_rule_template.scheduled_template.0.severity
  query                      = data.azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_template.analytics_rule_template.scheduled_template.0.query
  description                = data.azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_template.analytics_rule_template.scheduled_template.0.description
  query_frequency            = data.azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_template.analytics_rule_template.scheduled_template.0.query_frequency
  query_period               = data.azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_template.analytics_rule_template.scheduled_template.0.query_period
  tactics                    = data.azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_template.analytics_rule_template.scheduled_template.0.tactics
  trigger_operator           = data.azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_template.analytics_rule_template.scheduled_template.0.trigger_operator
  trigger_threshold          = data.azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_template.analytics_rule_template.scheduled_template.0.trigger_threshold
}
```

However, this needs an Azure Activity Solution to be installed. I don't see any option to install the solution(s) using a CLI or Terraform

[image]

I don't want to manually install these solutions. Is there a way to install these solutions using either a CLI or terraform?

Comment: As there is no direct cmdlet and terraform module to install **Azure Activity** as a `data connector` in `Microsoft Sentinel`. Check [Microsoft.SecurityInsights dataConnectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.securityinsights/dataconnectors?pivots=deployment-language-terraform) and **az cli** cmdlet , [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sentinel/data-connector?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sentinel-data-connector-create)

Comment: This is something that we can do with Azure CLI?

Answer (score -1):

Use Azure PowerShell:
Create an Azure PowerShell script to install the required solution. This script can use the Add-AzSentinelSolution cmdlet to install the solution by its name or ID.
Execute the script within your Terraform workflow using the local-exec provisioner. This allows you to run arbitrary commands within your Terraform configuration.

*Example PowerShell script:
PowerShell*

`Add-AzSentinelSolution -WorkspaceName "<workspace_name>" -SolutionName "Azure Activity"`

- Terraform configuration:

```
resource "azurerm_sentinel_data_connector_azure_security_center" "main" {
  ... existing configuration ...
}

provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = <<EOF
  powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ./install_solution.ps1
  EOF
}

resource "azurerm_sentinel_alert_rule_scheduled" "rare_operations" {
  ... existing configuration ...
}
```

check this link from terraform too. [terraform-azure](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs)

Comment: I don't see the cmdlet "Add-AzSentinelSolution" in MS documentation 
 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.securityinsights/?view=azps-11.3.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-6.0.0#security. Am I missing something?